# Spring Boot Thymeleaf allows client repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-thymeleaf

I'm actually encountering a problem with my view, in fact I'm tryng to display a pdf or at least a download button. The problem is that I cannot access the "pdf" directory that I created. He is as the same level as my JS directory.

The path is src/main /resources/static/pdf. When I check on my devtools, the request to the pdf is 404 error. and I'm tryng to reach them with relative path.

[Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3wTP.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this.

Here is my Security config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    /**
     * Laisse le controle aux controllers
     */
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth.anyRequest().permitAll()).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the file should be located under `src/main/resources/static/pdf`. The 404 message indicates no security issue. `http://localhost:8080/pdf/file123.pdf` should yield the correct file afterwards.

Comment: Yes sure, I forgot to put the main in my path, sorry. But it doesn't work....

Comment: What dependencies are you using? And how does your request look like?

Comment: I found my mistake I was using this syntax in my html:
th:src="${}"
instead of that :
th:src="@{}"